# Using AND in Select-Where

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, ado.net

I'm trying to use `AND` in the `SELECT` statement as below:

```
sqlc.ConnectionString = "Data source=. ; Database=LDatabase; integrated security=true";
    cmd.Connection=sqlc;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Books where Title like '" + txtboxbook.Text + "' and Author like '" + txtboxAuthor.Text + "'";

    sqlc.Open();
    SqlDataReader  R=cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource=R;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    if (R.HasRows == false)
        LMsg.Text = "No Items were found";
    else
        LMsg.Text =  GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString()+"Items were found";
    R.Close();
    sqlc.Close();
```

When I use one condition with no `AND` it works perfectly but when I add that troublesome `AND` it doesn't find what I've searched for?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for AND? do the books have the title AND the author that you send?

Comment: @FilipeSilva Yes they do. I copy them from database to make sure!

Comment: Narrow the problem down. Remove C# first. What happens if you run the same select in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: You use LIKE. are you putting % around the text you send in the parameters? Or are you selecting for exact matches?

Comment: @acfrancis Nothing, because I need ASP.Net fields for my select.

Comment: @FilipeSilva Doesn't make any difference. With or without % the result is the same

Comment: @Behnaz_Mardanzadeh. can you log what that string looks like when you execute it, and then run it in Management studio?

Comment: Like I said, narrow it down. Start testing the select in Mgmt Studio using static values (the ones you would've typed into your ASP.NET fields).

Comment: @acfrancis I replaced fields with real values. It didn't find them.

Comment: @acfrancis But it showed the correct result when I removed 'and' and the second condition.

Comment: It would be helpful to update the question with that information. Please show the full selects (successful and unsuccessful) you tested.

Answer (score 1):

You really should look at using [parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx#paght000002_step3).

```
//cmd.CommandText = "select * from Books where Title like '" + txtboxbook.Text + "' and Author like '" + txtboxAuthor.Text + "'";
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Books where Title like @title and Author like @author";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", txtboxbook.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", txtboxAuthor.Text);
```

Select * is also bad practice. Select only the columns you need.

Comment: I parameterized it at first but it wasn't successful. By the way I parameterized in an other way. I should try this one.

Comment: I tried your solution. I received this error:  Incorrect syntax near '@title'.

Comment: I removed the percent signs. You will need to add them separately, if you want to use them.